# Tensorflow generate TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

Im following [this](https://hackernoon.com/object-detection-in-google-colab-with-custom-dataset-5a7bb2b0e97e) tutorial to train a object detection neural network. I'm trying to create a TFRecord, like this:

```
!python ~/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py --label_map_path=label_map.pbtxt --data_dir=. --output_dir=. --num_shards=1
```

which outputs:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0626 13:47:09.201890 139729601312640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py:318: The name tf.app.run is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.app.run instead.

W0626 13:47:09.202526 139729601312640 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /root/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py:132: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 318, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 271, in main
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(FLAGS.label_map_path)
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 138, in load_labelmap
    label_map.ParseFromString(label_map_string)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I have no clue what the issue might be or how to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error says label map file cannot be parsed. Could you also paste your label_map.pbtxt file here?

Comment: @danyfang might it be because i didnt name my images like this: classname_index.jpg ?

Comment: As far as i know, label_map.pbtxt has nothing to do with image naming. It just contains classes names with ids. See [here](https://github.com/danyfang/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/data) for an example.